# Who or what inspired the character Geordi La Forge?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, inspiration

Fictional characters often are named and inspired by real people, for example  Sonequa Martin-Green's character [Michael Burnham is named](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/221577/why-is-her-name-michael-in-star-trek-discovery) after her character's biological father ["Mike" Burnham](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mike_Burnham). Where did the Star Trek creators get the name and inspiration for Geordi's character?

Comment: As a way to improve the question slightly, and address a concern that was raised in comments below, you could easily remove the assumption of "who" from this question.  Make it "What inspired the character Geordi La Forge?" and possibly change the body of the question to something like "where did the Star Trek creators get the initial idea and inspiration for Geordi's character?"

Comment: OK but that is really picking nits and I don't see it as an improvement. Living characters are never really inspired by a "what" like a grapefruit or an amazing dessert the director had one day. Generally "concepts" inspire concepts (whats) and people inspire characters (whos). I think "who" is really the only grammatically sensible pronoun here. But the votes are here for everyone to use. Try this: Ask a friend, "What are you named after?" Weird, right?

Comment: Sulu was inspired by Gene Rodenberry's desire for diversity on the show, and his idea of pan-asian peace.  He was named after the Sulu Sea, because it "touched all shores".  It's not always a who.  "who inspired this" does make unnecessary assumptions.  "Where did they come up with the idea" doesn't.

Comment: To clarify, I don't want to downvote this.  I've upvoted both answer and question, and I think the answer is awesome.  I just think that the question could still be improved further.

Comment: I would like the question edited to add a source for the example about the name Michael Burnham. Also: For the record, **asking and answering one's own questions is 100% legit on SFF.SE**. In the immortal words of Scoop Nisker "If you don't like the news, go out and make some of your own."

Comment: Add the link, I'm OK. Try not to make it unnecessarily complicated - it's a really simple question.

Comment: DaveInCaz's edit was the best version of this question.  As is now, the first statement is true but the second doesn't follow from it.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

A long-time *Star Trek* fan and quadriplegic named George La Forge had been following the original series and was an avid fan. His unfortunate passing in 1975 inspired creator Gene Roddenberry to focus on creating a new character with disabilities. Screenwriter David Gerrold suggested the name Geordi LaForge in respect of their fan. Mr. Roddenberry agreed the name would be a fitting tribute to Mr. La Forge's dedication to the franchise.

[Screenrant.com](https://screenrant.com/geordi-la-forge-star-trek-next-generation-trivia-facts/)